# nodejs exception handling on unexcpected event

Tags: node.js, error-handling, exception

I am working on a `nodejs` project and I had a major doubt/problem in `nodejs error handling`.

Whenever there is an exception caused by one of the request will the node stop the execution or will callback not returned of existing request, if so is there any way I can make the node to stop or throw exception after all the current request is completed.

I also wanted to ask if it is good to use `domain` as it is deprecated.